# How to show the value of radio button from database to html template in Django?

Tags: jquery, django, django-views, django-templates

To show the value in the edit page, in case of a simple textbox, we can show the value stored in the database using `{{ data.note }}` where data is rendered from the views.py to HTML template.

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
    <label>Notes <span class="red-color">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="important_note" class="form-control" id="important_note" value="{{ data.note }}">
</div>
```

If I want to do the same in case of the following group radio button, how can I show the selected value stored in the database table? (for example, Value B is stored in the database)

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-3" id="list_id">
    <label>Select List</label>
    <input type="radio" name="list" value ="A" id="A"> A <br>
    <input type="radio" name="list" value="B" id="B"> B <br>
    <input type="radio" name="list" value="C" id="C"> C <br>
    <input type="radio" name="list" value="D" id="D"> D <br>
    <input type="radio" name="list" id="E" value="E"> E
</div>
```

NOTE: I don't want to use forms.py in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `checked` like so `<input type="radio" name="list" value="B" id="B" checked>`

Comment: I meant I want the to show the stored value of radio button from the database using DTL. I can use the attribute checked only if I knew what value is stored in database.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by rendering the value into javascript. Find the value of each input, compare to the database value and then set the `checked` attribute.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('load', function() {
    $('#list_id :input').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('value') == '{{ data.note }}') {
            this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```